# How to handle concurrency issues in ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework Core when updating entities in a service?

Tags: c#, .net, crud

I have a MedService class in my ASP.NET Core application which uses Entity Framework Core to interact with my database. This service class is responsible for CRUD operations on the Med entities. Here's a simplified version of the service class:

```
  public class MedService:IMedService {

  private MedAppContext _context;

  public MedService(MedAppContext context)
  {
      _context = context;
  }

  public async Task<List<Med>> GetAllMedsAsync()
  {
      return await _context.Meds.ToListAsync();
  }

  public async Task<Med?> GetMedAsync(int Id)
  {
      return await _context.Meds.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == Id);
  }
  public async Task DeleteMedync(int Id)
  {
      var med = await GetMedAsync(Id);
      if (med == null) return;
      _context.Meds.Remove(med);
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  }

  public async Task UpdateMedAsync(Med med)
  {
      _context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
      _context.Meds.Update(med);
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

  }

  public async Task AddMedAsync(Med med)
  {
      if (med == null) return;

      await _context.Meds.AddAsync(new Med()
      {
          Name = med.Name,
          Count = med.Count,
          IngredientId = med.IngredientId,
          MedFormId = med.MedFormId,
          SideEffectsId=med.SideEffectsId,
          SideEffectRarityId=med.SideEffectRarityId,
      });

      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  }

  }
```

In my Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
```

Now, my concern is about handling concurrency issues, especially when updating entities using the UpdateMedAsync method. How can I ensure that I'm handling concurrency conflicts properly in this scenario? Should I be implementing any specific patterns or techniques within this service class or elsewhere in my ASP.NET Core application? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This CRUD class *causes* the concurrency issues. Remove all manual `Update` or `Add` methods. `SaveChanges` will persist *all* pending changes in a single database transaction. This means that `AddMedAsync` can easily `DELETE` 42 Doctors  while `DeleteMedync` can execute 10 `INSERT Patients`.  A DbContext is a multi-entity Unit of Work, not a database connection.  It doesn't need to be wrapped in a low-level CRUD class

Comment: DbSet.Update and DbSet.Add are *only* used to start tracking detached entities. In fact, `Update` is essentially an `AddOrUpdate`. If the entity's key is database generated, `Update` will attach a new entity in the `Modified` state if the key has a value or `Added` if it's null/default.

Comment: One approach is to just create a new dbContext for each call to the service. That should ensure each call is independent. It may be slightly less efficient in some cases, and you may need to manually attach some entities, but I still think it is an advantage overall.

Comment: There are at least two models of handling database concurrency, the optimistic concurrency model and the pesimistic one. Until you further specify which of the two you want to have, anything that follows is a speculation. Note also that if you search the docs for the two terms (optimistic and pessimistic concurrency in EF) you should be able to find information on how to both.

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations

**Optimistic Concurrency and Conflict Resolution Techniques**

In database management, concurrent modifications by multiple application instances can lead to inconsistencies. Optimistic concurrency, as implemented in EF Core, addresses this by assuming rare conflicts and avoiding upfront locks. Instead, conflicts are detected during the save operation, notifying the application to handle them accordingly.

*Concurrency tokens*, such as the Version property in EF Core, play a crucial role in detecting changes. These tokens are loaded and tracked during entity queries, and their values are compared during updates to ensure consistency. For example, a [Timestamp] attribute can be used to map a property to a SQL Server rowversion column, automatically updating it on each change.

When conflicts arise, techniques for resolution vary. Applications may inform users of conflicting changes, retry operations after re-querying data, or implement more sophisticated merging strategies. For instance, in EF Core, *DbUpdateConcurrencyException* is caught, and original values are refreshed to bypass subsequent checks.

**Considerations for Isolation Levels**

Another aspect of concurrency management involves isolation levels, particularly in ensuring data consistency. The repeatable reads transaction isolation level guarantees that a transaction sees data as it was when the transaction started, regardless of subsequent concurrent activity.

Implementation details of isolation levels vary across databases. For example, SQL Server's "repeatable read" level utilizes shared locks to prevent interference, while PostgreSQL's approach includes serialization errors to handle conflicts.

However, higher isolation levels may impact performance and require transactions to span all operations. It's crucial to weigh the benefits of data consistency against these drawbacks, especially considering the potential impact on concurrent performance.

---

This summarized article provides insights into managing concurrency in databases, covering optimistic concurrency, concurrency token implementation, conflict resolution techniques, and considerations for isolation levels.